# How to show icons on Tree Control in D365FO

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-365-operations

Please how to show icons on FormTreeControl in Dynamics 365 For Finance and Operations

[image: Icons in Tree Control in Dynamics AX 2012]

Here is my actual code, using to show icons in D365FO, #ResAppl Macro

public class IconsTree extends FormRun
{

```
public void init()
{
    SalesTable _Table;
    TreeItemIdx _TreeItemid;

    super();

    MyTreeView.deleteAll(); //This is my Tree Control on Form
    MyTreeView.lock();

    ImageListAppl dd = new ImageListAppl();
    ImageRes imageRes = dd.image(#ImageFormButtonGroup);

    MyTreeView.setImagelist(dd.imageList());



    while select * from _Table
    {

        _TreeItemid = SysFormTreeControl::addTreeItem(MyTreeView, "Sales Order :" + _Table.SalesId ,FormTreeAdd::Root,  _Table.RecId, #ImageOverlayYellowLock);
        SysFormTreeControl::addTreeItem(MyTreeView, " Customer Account : " + _Table.CustAccount ,_TreeItemid ,  _Table.RecId);
        SysFormTreeControl::expandTree(MyTreeView,_TreeItemid);
        SysFormTreeControl::setOverlayImage(MyTreeView, _TreeItemid, imageRes);
    }
}
```

}

and the result , no icons :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From what I have understood and what Microsoft indicates it's not allowed use image or icons on tree control in **D365FO**.

What is allowed [build extensible controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/user-interface/build-extensible-control), check this link [Check box support in tree controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/user-interface/check-box-tree-controls)

Comment: Is there any alternatives to do that ?

Comment: Making your own extensible control is the only option. You could build your own control based on https://www.jstree.com/

Comment: To add, every method you would expect is present on the tree control, so you would think it works...Microsoft just half-ported the `MorphX` control to the `React` framework. I spent way too many hours trying to get it to work in D365 as well before someone at Microsoft told me to make my own control.